# increase the gain of an incoming audio stream

Tags: audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, javasound, internet-radio

all my questions relate to the same problem: adjusting the gain of an external audio stream on a webpage.

when you visit my webpage, you will hear an audio stream from my online radio station.

the audio stream is delivered through a flash player which is embedded into the page.

the flash player cannot be changed, the only variable in the code i was provided was to change the address of the stream that is played. the stream is an online radio station.

the station broadcasts at a level which is way below 0dB so using the volume control does very little to increase the sound heard on the website.

i need a code that i can add to my standard player code:

to increase the gain of the stream heard on the website OR a completely new Flash player code that will stream the audio from the station as well as increase the gain of the audio.

please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot (currently) modify that stream client-side.  You cannot increase the gain.  All you can do is set the volume at 0dB with a custom Flash player, and it's likely the one you are using now already has it there.

The only way to modify the audio content is to do the compression and gain server-side, and re-encode the stream before sending to the clients.  You will have a loss of quality, as you are reducing dynamic range and lossy-compressing data that was already lossy-compressed.  The best thing to do is fix the source material.